# Tensorflow TimeFreqLSTMCell: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement this [LSTM cell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/TimeFreqLSTMCell) but keep getting the error below. My code for running it is:

```
lstm_cell =rnn.TimeFreqLSTMCell(n_hidden, use_peepholes=True, feature_size= 22, forget_bias=1.0)
outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

The error occurs on the second line. Error trace is below , I get that the error is saying it can't do a division due to data type mismatch but not sure how to fix.

```
> 44     pred = RNN(x, weights, biases,n_steps)
     45     cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
     46     optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

<ipython-input-53-80cdb90dd338> in RNN(x, weights, biases, n_steps)
     13     elif cellType == "TimeFreqLSTMCell":
     14         lstm_cell =rnn.TimeFreqLSTMCell(n_hidden, use_peepholes=True, feature_size= 22, forget_bias=1.0)
---> 15         outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
     16     elif cellType == "GridLSTMCell":
     17         lstm_cell =rnn.GridLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py in static_rnn(cell, inputs, initial_state, dtype, sequence_length, scope)
   1210             state_size=cell.state_size)
   1211       else:
-> 1212         (output, state) = call_cell()
   1213 
   1214       outputs.append(output)

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py in <lambda>()
   1197         varscope.reuse_variables()
   1198       # pylint: disable=cell-var-from-loop
-> 1199       call_cell = lambda: cell(input_, state)
   1200       # pylint: enable=cell-var-from-loop
   1201       if sequence_length is not None:

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py in __call__(self, inputs, state, scope)
    178       with vs.variable_scope(vs.get_variable_scope(),
    179                              custom_getter=self._rnn_get_variable):
--> 180         return super(RNNCell, self).__call__(inputs, state)
    181 
    182   def _rnn_get_variable(self, getter, *args, **kwargs):

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    439         # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
    440         self._assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
--> 441         outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    442 
    443         # Apply activity regularization.

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py in call(self, inputs, state)
    336     tanh = math_ops.tanh
    337 
--> 338     freq_inputs = self._make_tf_features(inputs)
    339     dtype = inputs.dtype
    340     actual_input_size = freq_inputs[0].get_shape().as_list()[1]

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py in _make_tf_features(self, input_feat)
    415       raise ValueError("Cannot infer input_size from static shape inference.")
    416     num_feats = int((input_size - self._feature_size) / (
--> 417         self._frequency_skip)) + 1
    418     freq_inputs = []
    419     for f in range(num_feats):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: What is the shape of your input `x` . To use with static_rnn, it should  be similar to `[batch_size, sequence_length, input_dim]`

Comment: Yes it is a 3d array but it then gets transformed by this `x = tf.unstack(x, n_steps, 1)`  before it gets fed into the cell. This works when I used the BasicLSTMCell.

Comment: I had the same issue and opened an issue at github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16100